# XML validation against schema fails in Java with namespace

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xml-namespaces, javax.xml

I need to write Java code that validates XML against a schema. The validation fails for some reason I don't understand, giving the following exception:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'root'
```

Schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified"
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.com"
    xmlns="http://www.example.com"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="root" type="rootType"/>
    <xs:simpleType name="rootType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:integer"/>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns="http://www.example.com">1</root>
```

Java code:

```
try (InputStream xmlStream = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("a.xml");
        InputStream xsdStream = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("a.xsd")) {
    DocumentBuilder parser = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = parser.parse(xmlStream);
    SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    StreamSource schemaFile = new StreamSource(xsdStream);
    Schema schema = factory.newSchema(schemaFile);
    Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
    validator.validate(new DOMSource(document));
}
```

Validation succeeds if I remove all references to the namespace "http://www.example.com". Is there anything wrong with the schema, the XML or the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should enable namespaces in the builder factory.

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory fact = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    fact.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder parser = fact.newDocumentBuilder();
```

Answer (score 2):

You should make the `DocumentBuilderFactory` namespace-aware using the `setNamespaceAware()` method.